# AndroidAsync websockets not working

Tags: java, android, websocket, socket.io, androidasync-koush

I am using this [AndroidSync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) library by koush to to create websocket (server/client) and transfer data between two android devices. The two devices are connected via wifi(one is Wifi AP and other is connected to it ). I get TimeoutException in client device after 4-5 sec of sending the request.
This is what I have done so far..

**ServerActivity.java**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server);

    mSockets = new ArrayList<WebSocket>();
    mAsyncHttpServer = new AsyncHttpServer();
    mWebSocketCallback = new AsyncHttpServer.WebSocketRequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(final WebSocket webSocket, RequestHeaders headers) {
            mSockets.add(webSocket);
            webSocket.send("Welcome Client");
            webSocket.setClosedCallback(new CompletedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception ex) {
                    try {
                        if (ex != null)
                            Log.e("WebSocket", "Error");
                    } finally {
                        mSockets.remove(webSocket);
                    }
                }
            });
            webSocket.setStringCallback(new WebSocket.StringCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStringAvailable(String s) {
                    Log.d("SERVERTAG",s);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    mAsyncHttpServer.websocket("/",mWebSocketCallback);
    mAsyncHttpServer.listen(Utils.PORT_NUMBER);

    Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButtonS);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for(WebSocket socket : mSockets) {
                socket.send("Server sent a string");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**ClientActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    //Resolve IP address
    int ipAddress = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
    String hostAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ipAddress);
    hostAddress = "http://" + hostAddress + ":" +Utils.PORT_NUMBER;
    Log.d("CLIENTTAG", "address is " + hostAddress);

    mWebSocketConnectCallback = new AsyncHttpClient.WebSocketConnectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception ex, WebSocket webSocket) {
            if (ex != null) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            webSocket.send("Hello Server");
            webSocket.setStringCallback(new WebSocket.StringCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStringAvailable(String s) {
                    Log.d("CLIENTTAG",s);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mAsyncHttpClient = AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance();
    mAsyncHttpClient.websocket(hostAddress, null, mWebSocketConnectCallback);

}
```

This is what I get in logcat in client device.

```
10-21 19:50:49.289      742-945/com.haloappstudio.musichub W/System.err﹕ java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
10-21 19:50:49.289      742-945/com.haloappstudio.musichub W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient$2.run(AsyncHttpClient.java:240)
10-21 19:50:49.289      742-945/com.haloappstudio.musichub W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.lockAndRunQueue(AsyncServer.java:683)
10-21 19:50:49.289      742-945/com.haloappstudio.musichub W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:700)
10-21 19:50:49.289      742-945/com.haloappstudio.musichub W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:608)
10-21 19:50:49.289      742-945/com.haloappstudio.musichub W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$700(AsyncServer.java:37)
10-21 19:50:49.289      742-945/com.haloappstudio.musichub W/System.err﹕ at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$13.run(AsyncServer.java:557)
```

I haven't really done socket programming before. Can anyone please help me out here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, as @jrandaz said the problem was with IP address of server.

Turns out

`WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress()`

returns device's own IP address not the address of wifi hotspot device to which it's connected.
I used `192.168.43.1` which is the default IP address of wifi hotspot in android and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, have you tried passing http in where you have null at?

`mAsyncHttpClient.websocket(hostAddress, null, mWebSocketConnectCallback);`

Perhaps try

`mAsyncHttpClient.websocket(hostAddress, http, mWebSocketConnectCallback);`

Also, when you refer to both of your devices connected to Wifi, what do you mean by the second device is 'Connected to it'.  (Would clarify this via comment but don't have enough points) It is possible that you are not receiving the correct IP address when connecting to demo server.

Comment: I mean the second device is connected to wifi hotspot of first device.